# for (k, v) in data_dict.items: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items' --

Tags: python, list, attributeerror, items

I am trying to use the json data which is in data_dict and use it in the for loop to segregate the   json data into different attributes with the help of k and v. But I got struck with the above AttributeError, any help is much appreciated.

```py
with open('Yelp.json', 'r',encoding= 'utf8') as f: 
    data_dict = json.load(f)
    count = 0
    for (k, v) in data_dict.items():
        for values in v: 
            #print()
            for key in values:
                if str(key) == 'business_id':
                    lsthrs[str(key)]=values[key] 
                    lstcat[str(key)]=values[key]
                    lstnbh[str(key)]=values[key]
                    lstatr[str(key)]=values[key]
                    lstgoodforatr[str(key)]=values[key]
                    lstparkingatr[str(key)]=values[key]
                    lstambienceatr[str(key)]=values[key]
                tep = values[key]
```

Comment: Seems like `data_dict` is a list, maybe your JSON file contains an array (loaded as a list in Python)?

Comment: What does your JSON file look like?

Comment: It's an array of data with multiple business data in it.

Comment: you should paste a minimal json content instead of describing it as 'an array of data'

Comment: [{"business_id":"6iYb2HFDywm3zjuRg0shjw","name":"Oskar Blues Taproom","address":"921 Pearl St","city":"Boulder","state":"CO","postal_code":"80302","latitude":40.0175444,"longitude":-105.2833481,"stars":4.0,"review_count":86,"is_open":1,"attributes":{"RestaurantsTableService":"True","WiFi":"u'free'","BikeParking":"True","BusinessParking":"{'garage': False, 'street': True, 'validated': False, 'lot': False, 'valet': False}","BusinessAcceptsCreditCards":"True","RestaurantsReservations":"False","WheelchairAccessible":"True","Caters":"True","OutdoorSeating":"True","RestaurantsGoodForGrou

Comment: in the same way there is data for 107888 business id's

Comment: If your file starts with a `[` its and indication that it is an array. Just iterate as `for values in data_dict` (although now you may need to change the variable name)

Comment: it still shows the same error: ''for values in data_dict.items():AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: Any suggestions it is still throwing me the same error

Comment: @SameeraNandan what @aaossa implies is: remove `.items()`. of course you may get some  other errror, but the `'list' object has no attribute 'items'` error should be gone.

Answer (score 1):

Since your JSON file starts with a `[` (as mentioned in the question comments), the contents of your file will be loaded (at `json.load`) as a list of dictionaries:

```
with open('Yelp.json', 'r',encoding= 'utf8') as f:
    data_list = json.load(f) # Since `data_dict` is actually a list
    count = 0
    # To find the keys of each object, you could use this print:
    # print(data_list[0].keys())
    for values in data_list:  # Remember that `values` is a dict
        for key in values:  # The keys of the `values` dict
            if str(key) == 'business_id':
                ...
```

Comment: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/samee/PycharmProjects/LAB2CIS593/Businessdata.py", line 142, in <module>
    data_list = json.load(f)
  File "C:\Users\samee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return load(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\samee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return load(fp.read(),'

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
Nowit is throwing me this error an Idea how to deal with this

Comment: Seems like you're passing a string instead of `f` to your `json.load`. Print `f` and its type. The code you provided in your question should work as intended.

Comment: Can you please connect with me and help me in any chat medium I am unable get it.  have been trying to crack this since 2 days

Comment: Can anyone help me with this in chat, I could not get through this

Comment: what do you mean by {f} and its type? can you please explain it to me clearly.

Comment: <class '_io.TextIOWrapper'> <_io.TextIOWrapper name='businessValidForm.json' mode='r' encoding='utf8'> this is the output

Comment: above is the input any update on this, How can I proceed further with this now?

Comment: File "C:\Users\samee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 341, in load
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not TextIOWrapper

Comment: I am using the second one, I haven't done any modifications on my json file.

Comment: If I change the json file like below do I need to use anything different 

{[
{"business_id": "5UmKMjUEUNdYWqANhGckJw", "full_address": "4734 Lebanon Church Rd\nDravosburg, PA 15034", "hours": {"Friday": {"close": "21:00", "open": "11:00"}, "Tuesday": {"close": "21:00", "open": "11:00"}, "Thursday": {"close": "21:00", "open": "11:00"}, "Wednesday": {"close": "21:00", "open": "11:00"}, "Monday": {"close": "21:00", "open": "11:00"}}, "open": true, "categories": ["Fast Food", "Restaurants"], "city": "Dravosburg", "review_count": 4, "name": "Mr Hoagie", "neighborhoods":

Comment: [
{"business_id": "5UmKMjUEUNdYWqANhGckJw", "full_address": "4734 Lebanon Church Rd\nDravosburg, PA 15034", "hours": {"Friday": {"close": "21:00", "open": "11:0 


I have changed it back to array again will this be considered

Comment: Yes, that was always valid. I don't know why are you changing the JSON file, it was fine since the beginning. Please update your question with any change you've made or ask a new question if you have another problem. Again, I'm not sure what changed.